# Next.js: Server high CPU usage when ISR revalidate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

We have an issue on our production server, with high CPU usage(100% spikes) during regenerating page on revalidate(once in 300sec for each page) even if there is only one user. Is it ok? Because it looks like we don't have any other problems exept maybe slow image loading. Any thoughts?

Server params: 2 cores processor 2.1GHz, 2Gb RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was caused by wrong `<a>` tag nesting, for `next/link` component, In our case we had `<a>` tag not as direct child of `next/link` but as a child of a functional component without `React.forwardRef`, it looks like this kind of wrong usage triggers `getStaticProps` function to run  during `next/link` `prefetch`, so every time we have some link to another page in viewport it triggers `getStaticProps` of that page and several functions of that type in same time overload CPU.

Propper usage of `<a>` tag fix the issue.